# Android:Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm currently having some issues with this code. Any help is appreciated. Below is the exception.

```
public void onPass(View v)
{

    String sn1=et1.getText().toString();
    String sn2=et2.getText().toString();

    int i1=Integer.parseInt(sn1.trim());
    int i2=Integer.parseInt(sn2.trim());
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Act2.class);
    i.putExtra("k1",i1 );
    i.putExtra("k2", i2);

    startActivity(i);
 }
```

**The Logcat output**:

```
05-14 15:28:45.099: E/AndroidRuntime(368): Caused by: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7b
```

Comment: please check that sn1 and sn2 have values , may clean and build also helps

Comment: use this int i1=Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());

Comment: @Raghunandan I think exception is not because of that and is not in this code, instead he is try to set `int` value to his EditText's

Comment: @Raghunandan You are assigning int value to String, it will throw Exception, as `Integer.parseInt` will return `int` value

Comment: @Pragnani you are right. op may be setting int value to edittext. In that case et1.setText(Integer.toString(intvalue));

Comment: @user2380749: Show your layout xml file. May be you have given inappropriate values of id attribute of your edittexts..

Answer (score 0):

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7b
```

You will get this Exception, when you are tring to set `int` value to the `TextView, or Edittext  or Button, Toast` etc views.

When you set the `int` value to the views, it will consider them as `String resources`, it will try to search for the string resource with the specified id, and will throw `Resources$NotFoundException`

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
         et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        
         bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        
    
    }//rest above part of the programme if u can help

Answer (score 0):

Declare the TextView, or Edittext, after the class and try accessing it. For example,

```
 public class example extends Activity{
EditText ediValue ;
TextView tviewWholeData;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     ediValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tedit);             
    tviewWholeData =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tviewwholedata);
```

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
         et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        
         bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        
    
    }
this is the rest above part of the programe if u can help

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.lay2);
  
  et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.leditText1);
   et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.leditText2);
  
  btn1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.lbutton1);
  
  Bundle b1=getIntent().getExtras();
  
  i3= b1.getInt("k1");
  i4= b1.getInt("k2");
  
  et1.setText(i3);
  et2.setText(i4);  
  /*i1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
  i2=Integer.parseInt(s2);
  */ 
  
  }
  
  public void onAdd(View v)
  { int i5= i3+i4;
   Toast.makeText(this, "its "+i5+" ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }